# How to access a View by an ID of the android namespace

Tags: android, namespaces, view, hierarchy

[image]

In hierarchy viewer there are several IDs as shown above, for example "id/timepicker_input".
But I can't find a respective timepicker_input - ID when typing

```
myNumberPicker.findViewById(android.R.id. ...? );
```

So how to access these Views by their ID?

Answer (score 1):

Make shure there is no `import android.R...` defined and build your project after altering your layouts.

Comment: Thanks. But there is no import which could affect the ID placeholder in any way. I don't see an id "timepicker_input" in autocompletion.